# "argline" argument not working in Maven Surefire Eclipse JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

In Eclipse I do "Run As" "Maven test" or "Maven build" and the tests fail. In "Run Configurations" I have set the Goals as

> clean package -DargLine="-Darg1=7070 -Darg2=9"

I've also tried setting above arguments via pom.xml like so:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Darg1=7070 -Darg2=9</argLine>
                </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

My JUnit TestCase is:

```
    public class TestCase1 {

    private static String arg1;
    private static String arg2;

    @Test
        public void testStart() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("arg1: " + arg1);
            System.out.println("arg2: " + arg2);
        }
    }
```

Both arg1 and arg2 come as null.

If anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: The test never uses the program arguments. And arg1 and arg2 are never initialized, hence they are null.

Comment: The test uses these arguments, I've just posted code to show that they are null. And shouldn't these be initialized via pom.xml ? I mean, shouldn't arg1 be 7070 and arg2 be 9? If not, then what's the way to initialize them from pom.xml?

Comment: You are not fetching the arguments but only checking value of not initialized variables, which are null of course

Answer (score 1):

The fields are not automatically fetched. You need to call `System.getProperty(String name)`.

```
private static String arg1 = System.getProperty("arg1");
private static String arg2 = System.getProperty("arg2");
```